# Как мне улучшить код, чтоб спарсить карту любого сайта?

Tags: php

У меня есть метод "parse". Сейчас мы с помощью рекурсии, ходим по ссылкам сайта и берем, только первую ссылку со страниц.
А как мне брать все ссылки каждого уровня сайта,чтоб в итоге получить карту сайта

--index.php--

```
    function parse($url){
      $url = $this->readUrl($url);
      if( !$url or $this->cacheurl[$url] or $this->cacheurl[preg_replace('#/$#','',$url)] )
        return false;

      $this->_allcount--;

      if( $this->_allcount<=0 )
        return false;

      $this->cacheurl[$url] = true;
      $item = array();  

      $data = str_get_html(request($url));
      $item['url'] = $url;
      $item['title'] = count($data->find('title'))?$data->find('title',0)->plaintext:'';
      $this->result[] = $item;

      if(count($data->find('a'))){
        foreach($data->find('a') as $a){
            $this->parse($a->href);
        }
      }
      $data->clear();
      unset($data);

   }
   function printresult(){

    foreach($this->result as $item){
        echo ''.$item['title'].' - <small>'.$item['url'].'</small>';
        //echo '<p style="margin:20px 0px;background:#eee; padding:20px;">'.$item['text'].'</p>';           
    };


    exit();
  }
```

Comment: Может проще sitemap.xml поискать на сайтах

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужен php-скрипт который ходит по ссылкам любого сайта(начиная с главной страницы) и строит sitemap. Результатом работы программы должен быть sitemap.xml. А изначально я хочу сделать парсер сайтов

Answer (score 1):

Анастасия, вы в начале очень длинного пути.

- Что если страниц на Вашем сайте будет миллион или больше?
- Что если вы попадёте в цикл во время обхода по рекурсии(две страницы будут ссылаться одна на другую)
- Что если на сайте будет ссылка на другой сайт?(соцсети например) вы так можете весь интернет одним вызовом просканировать:-)
- Что если Вам будут попадаться ссылки разного формата Абсолютные(http://ya.ru/test), относительные ("index.php" находящийся по адресу "http://text.ru/folder/sub-folder/") или просто рутовая ссылка ("/folder/index.php")
- Еще среди ссылок могут попадаться картинки и другой медиа-контент
- Что если по какой-то ссылке вы получите ошибку (40X/500)

Есть ещё очень много вопросов.
И далеко не все из них могут решить даже самые светлые умы из разработчиков поиска Google. Например влияет тот или иной парамерт в адресной строке на содержимое страницы(т.е. как влияет параметр param в ссылке http://test.ru?param=value на содержимое)

И такую задачу лучше не выполнять в одном скрипте и по запросу.
Для работы лучше использовать хранилище в качестве очереди.
И желательно не изобретать велосипед а поискать уже готовые библиотеки.
Искать лучше по запросу "php Crawler" - именно так называется то что Вы делаете.
В поиске куча библиотек, описания всех возможных подводных камней и многое другое.

Поиск:

https://www.google.ru/search?q=php%20crawler&oq=php%20crawler